# How does Rails maintain a has_one relationship along a has_many relationship of the same type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a project I am currently working on, I noticed that if I had a `has_one` and a `has_many` referencing the same type of object then Rails could distinguish between the object that was referenced as a `has_one` and the object that was referenced as a `has_many` in subsequent console sessions.

For example, take the following two models:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
  has_one :bar
end


class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

If I create a new record of type `Foo` with a set of `Bar` instances and a separate `Bar` instance in the `Foo#bar` attribute and then restart the console I find that the original `Foo` instance still references the separate `Bar` instance as `bar`. That separate instance now appears in the list of `Bar` instances returned by `Foo#bars`. Is this normal behaviour or a bit of a fluke?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? This could lead to quite unpredictable results for the `bar` association because you can't be 100% certain _which_ record it will return from the set.

Comment: That's precisely what I suspected, and I was already on the way to define a different column and foreign key for my has_one relationship. I just found it interesting that the framework seemed to remember which one was which and so I thought I'd ask the experts for an explanation. It might have turned out to be useful - you don't know if you don't ask!

Comment: I agree that it's helpful to ask. I was sincerely curious what you were trying to accomplish because I tend to find that that reveals how best to answer a question like this one.

Comment: I am working on an app which stores peoples friends details - a little like a glorified contact list. It's part of a larger application. I want to reuse the class that I have written for storing contact details to store the user's details. So I want to have a has_one that refers to one Person instance for the user's details and a has_many that refers to other Person instances for the user's contacts.

Comment: Are these friend details like a social network? As in, you have a user who has a friend, who is also a user? If so, that would need to be modeled differently. If you just have a user that has contacts that aren't necessarily other users, you'd want to model it a little differently.

Comment: I'd wire things up like this through an intermediary `Friendship` model for the friends: https://gist.github.com/chrisdpeters/e7ae0197218651b14571 (Or name it `UserContact` if you want it to be more generic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, because `has_many` and `has_one` have the same concept in DB, they are the relation having 0...n (zero to many) others!

But the different is meaning:

- `has_one` has the meaning `0..1`, otherwise, `has_many` is `0..n`, you see `n maybe equal 1`
- Moreover, `has_one` & `has_many` help rails understand what you are doing for query, for example:

**Foo.first.bar**

```
=> SELECT  "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."foo_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["foo_id", 234]]
```

**Foo.first.bars** (without limit 1)

```
=> SELECT  "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."foo_id" = $1 [["foo_id", 234]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end


class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :foo_single, :foreign_key=>"foo_single_id", :class_name=>"Foo" 
end
```

By doing so, you would separate the "bars". If a bar has a foo_single_id, it would indicate that you are looking up the 1-to-1 relationship. If the Bar has a foo_id, then it'd be the 1-to-many.

It needs to be completed for the Foo has_one bar relationship.